# Problem with foreach loop and $_GET

Tags: php

I have a very simple foreach loop

```
foreach($tv as $id => $channel) {
$ID = $_GET['ID'];
if($ID == $id){$class = "currentt";}
echo '<a href="http://www.mysite.com/tst.php?ID='.$id.'"     class="'.$class.'">'.$channel.'</a><br>';
 }
```

With url query, with every click the current class repeated. How can avoid this?
Thanks alot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$ID = $_GET['ID'];
foreach($tv as $id => $channel) {
    $class = $ID == $id ? "currentt": '';
    echo "<a href='http://www.mysite.com/tst.php?ID=$id' class='$class'>$channel</a><br>";
}
```

The problem you had was that you never change `$class` after it was assigned value `'currentt'`.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `$class = $ID == $id ? "currentt" : '';`?

Comment: Thanks for help, I think my code's problem is that there is not "esle" condition in it.